# Matching Pairs Checking Cards Match

Tags: java, android

I am creating this matching pairs game, i am on the part where it checks if the cards match, if not flip them back over. I don't know what is wrong with my code that checks them, could anyone help?

```
Integer PendingImage;
Integer PendingImage2;    

FirstImageCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FirstImageCard.setImageResource(CardId[0]);
            if (PendingImage == null) {
                PendingImage = CardId[0];

            }
            else if(PendingImage != null && PendingImage2 == null) {
                PendingImage2 = CardId[0];

            }
            if (PendingImage != null && PendingImage2 != null) {
                if (PendingImage.equals(PendingImage2)) {
                    PendingImage = null;
                    PendingImage2 = null;

                }
            }
            else {
                FirstImageCard.setImageResource(R.drawable.cardbacks);
            }
        }
    });

    SecondImageCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            SecondImageCard.setImageResource(CardId[0]);
            if (PendingImage == null) {
                PendingImage = CardId[0];

            }
            else if (PendingImage != null && PendingImage2 == null) {
                PendingImage2 = CardId[0];

            }
            if (PendingImage != null && PendingImage2 != null) {
                if (PendingImage.equals(PendingImage2)) {
                    PendingImage = null;
                    PendingImage2 = null;

                }
            }
            else {
                SecondImageCard.setImageResource(R.drawable.cardbacks);
            }
        }
    });

    ThirdImageCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ThirdImageCard.setImageResource(CardId[1]);
            if (PendingImage == null) {
                PendingImage = CardId[1];

            }
            else if (PendingImage != null && PendingImage2 == null) {
                PendingImage2 = CardId[1];

            }
            else if (PendingImage != null && PendingImage2 != null) {
                if (PendingImage.equals(PendingImage2)) {
                    PendingImage = null;
                    PendingImage2 = null;

                }
            }
            else {
                ThirdImageCard.setImageResource(R.drawable.cardbacks);
            }
        }
    });

    FourthImageCard.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            FourthImageCard.setImageResource(CardId[1]);
            if (PendingImage == null) {
                PendingImage = CardId[1];

            }
            else if (PendingImage != null && PendingImage2 == null) {
                PendingImage2 = CardId[1];

            }
            else if (PendingImage != null && PendingImage2 != null) {
                if (PendingImage.equals(PendingImage2)) {
                    PendingImage = null;
                    PendingImage2 = null;

                }
            }
            else {
                FourthImageCard.setImageResource(R.drawable.cardbacks);
            }
        }
    });
```

This code kinda works in the sense that it checks if they match but if they don't it doesn't flip it back over and on the first click if the card it doesn't flip it over until you click it again, if i change the if to else if, it works with the card flipping first time but it doesn't check if they match, any help?